# gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale

Tags: ubuntu

This is my error

```
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale
```

I want to start the gedit in my account.
but using sudo, it's running.
I don't know why..?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
I set up anaconda2.7, Opencv2.4.12, cuDNN v4, CUDA 7.5, Caffe.

and my PASS is

```
export PATH="/home/myAccount/anaconda2/bin:$PATH";
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin/:$PATH; 
export PATH=/usr/local/:$PATH;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/myAccount/anaconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
export PYTHONPATH=/home/myAccount/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH;
```

also, i added sudoers "myAccount ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"

Help me~~~.

How can I run the gedit in my account??

Comment: first take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm so foolish.

Because i forgot to add a myAccount in /etc/hosts.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be in the .../anaconda2/lib part in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Resetting that should work.

```
LD_LIBRARYPATH= gedit
```